# Use the same VM wtih VMware player and Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-player

I have some problems with my VMWare player installation (possibly a bug). So, I want to try to run my VMs with VirtualBox, **without** converting them.

So, is it safe to run my VMs with VirtualBox and when the VMware player's bug is fixed stop using VirtualBox and use the Player again?

Comment: What version of both applications are you using?  Virtualbox has no problem supporting the same file extension that VmWare uses.  VMWare does not support Virtualbox's extension so that will require a conversion at least once.

Comment: Virtual Box: 4.2.8
VMware: 5.0.2

Answer (score 2):

I tried and found the following issues.

1. You can run the same VM on VMWare and VirtualBox, as long as you do not use Snapshots
2. You do do convert VMDKs to other formats
3. You do not start the Guest additions (or the VMWare Tools) automatically.

On a side note, in **my** case Virtualbox is faster and thus, I kept that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can not copy virtual machines, but you can export/import them  to common open format or use the hard disk image in several machines. 
Secondly, different virtualization systems emulate completely different devices. Linux guest is OK, but Windows may get upset. 
Finally, you can't use snapshots and other similar things cause they are not exported.

Comment: I don't want to copy them. I want to use Player and Virtualbox on the same host machine. I don't want to use snapshots, just to use VB until the player is fixed.

Comment: Actually you can copy virtual machines.  Its a simple process to change the UID.

Comment: I don't want to do that. I want the SAME VM to be used from different Hypervisors at different times. That's all.